# Compare two large JSON field value in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have two large JSON file and i want to compare the first file data with another json file data using java.The json file data are unstructured.I want to compare the data (eg. senderId and orderId of 1st file with the senderId and orderId of 2nd file).If they are matched then its fine,if there is any difference i want to store in new file.
I m new to json and jackson.
Its helpful for me if someone help me with sample code
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? This ain't no platform to get work done free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonUnit to do what you want. There are code examples on the Github page:

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit